# Launching compilation extension "s3eIOSAppStoreBilling" on marmalade 7.8.1 can't find files

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, billing, marmalade

I'm just start compiling "clean" extension "s3eIOSAppStoreBilling" on new version of marmalade -  7.8.1.

While compiling, some files can't be found:

```
#import "NSString+LimitedExtension.h
#import "s3eEdk_iphone_billingsupport.h
```

that using in file s3eIOSAppStoreBilling_platform.m